# Export Steam user scores into excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, steam, steam-web-api

I would like to create an excel sheet listing the user review scores of random games, along with the number of reviews overall.
E.x:

| Name | Review Score | # of Reviews |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Random Game | 78% | 230 |
| Another Random Game | 96% | 3021 |

I could have a website give me a game and log the information manually, but if possible, I would like to write some code to grab that data and populate it into a file so that I can quickly accumulate a few hundred or thousand entries.

I've done a bit of googling, and I'm not quite sure where to start. What would be the best method for pulling data from steam?

Answer (score 1):

You can either call their API on your own, or use `steamreviews` library.

`steamreviews` https://pypi.org/project/steamreviews/

manually call API: https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/getreviews

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Seems there is a method to get reviews from the API, as shown in the other answer.**

From what I can see from the API there is no specific endpoint to get review information. However, you could scrape a game's page and get the review information, as it is available on there.

As an example, [Grand Theft Auto 5's store page](https://store.steampowered.com/app/271590/Grand_Theft_Auto_V/) shows the following.

[image: Steam reviews on the GTA 5 store page.]

You could then download the webpage using Requests, and process the HTML using BeautifulSoup.

[image: HTML review data.]

You can use the same method as above to find the *exact* amount of positive/negative reviews, as that is also available at the bottom of the page just above the review section as a filter.

[image]